# How do I go about putting a chunk of code into a Variable?

Tags: macos, applescript

I've been trying to get chunks of code into variables so I could easily just place the variable and shorten the code by a lot.

Here's the code that I want to turn into a variable-

```
set recipientName to "Joe"
set recipientAddress to "joel@here.com"
set theSubject to "Type your subject here!"
set theContent to "Type your message content here!"

tell application "Mail"

        ##Create the message
        set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:theSubject, content:theContent, visible:true}

        ##Set a recipient
        tell theMessage
                make new to recipient with properties {name:recipientName, address:recipientAddress}

                ##Send the Message
                send

        end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Please read the help center before posting questions. There is no reason to mention your last post was put on hold for being too broad. There is a reason it was put on hold for that. No need to mention that in this question. To get the best answers provide only the details required to answer your question in a concise detailed way.

Comment: @CharlieFish Thanks for the edit tip. However, you don't need to down vote my question. Doing that just makes it harder for me to get answers.

Comment: Just as a suggestion I'd say your question is still on the broad side. Not sure why you think I was the one who down voted it.

Comment: @CharlieFish Just an assumption. You are the only one commenting, so thats all I have to go on. If thats not you, sorry. However, are you able to help? I would appreciate it.

Comment: Are you hoping to then execute the variable somehow - like `eval`?

Comment: Not sure what you meant by "like eval"

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am hoping to execute the variable, but I also want to know how to put other chunks of code into a variable, as to then be executed. Remember, this is only a small chunk of the full code.

Comment: This may help... http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=10445

Comment: @MarkSetchell Unfortunately, no. I don't understand what they're saying. It doesn't look like they're putting a chunk of code as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to wrap your Mail code in a reusable handler, like this:

```
to sendEmail(recipientName, recipientAddress, theSubject, theContent)
    tell application "Mail"

        ##Create the message
        set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:theSubject, content:theContent, visible:true}

        ##Set a recipient
        tell theMessage
            make new to recipient with properties {name:recipientName, address:recipientAddress}

            ##Send the Message
            send

        end tell
    end tell
end sendEmail
```

You can then send commands with different parameters at any time like this:

```
sendEmail("Joe", "joel@here.com", "Type your subject here!", "Type your message content here!")
```

and this:

```
sendEmail("Sam", "sam@there.com", "Type another subject here!", "Type more message content here!")
```

etc.

Comment: If you look at the entire piece of code, you'll see why I'm trying to shorten this as much as possible. Seeing the full code should help you see what I'm trying to do, because I also want the variables to be able to be manipulated using dialogs and answers. I'll give you a dropbox so you can see and try it. https://www.dropbox.com/s/57bqrsx85m065pg/Messy%20Code.rtf?dl=0

Comment: Ignore the "spammer" part of it. This is mainly as a messaging piece and is also supposed to be a secondary message sender. I tend to like using applescript to send mail than I do mail. Its easier to just open an applescript, go through dialogs, and boom. Done.

Comment: There's nothing magical to programming, nor anything new or novel in what you're trying to do. You're trying to eliminate unnecessary duplication of code. Wrapping a block of code in a repeat loop is one basic tool for this; wrapping it in a reusable handler is another, more powerful, flexible option. I recommend you skim through a high school textbook to make sure you grasp the basic skills for building a program, then get yourself a copy of McConnell's Code Complete to really nail down the concepts and techniques that will enable you to produce really good, efficient, tight code.

Comment: p.s. If you want something specifically AppleScript-y, I coauthored the third edition of Apress's [Learn AppleScript](https://www.amazon.com/Learn-AppleScript-Comprehensive-Scripting-Automation/dp/1430223618/). Obviously it covers a lot more territory, but it does include some discussion of both language features (handlers, script objects) and concepts (ch. 29, IIRC) for writing well structured, reusable code.

Comment: We dont have coding text books in my high school. We have computers, but I don't get to participate in those classes until I'm a Sophomore. And I do have a little higher than basic understanding of coding. I learn these things by analyzing what code others have wrote. Thats how I understood how the basic concepts work. Like if statements, variables, etc. I easily learned those from analyzing, testing, and continuously finding its limit. I do this with every term until I fully understand it, thats why I don't know how to put this chunk of code into a variable. I have no experience with it.

Comment: And I didn't get the ps post until I posted my most recent comment. Which was like 10 seconds ago.

Comment: Also, im 14. I don't have a credit card. And I'm not one for buying books at this time. I don't have money! xD

Comment: You overestimate your understanding of CS concepts, else you wouldn't be asking a question that makes no sense (outside of Lisp-y languages); see also: Dunning-Kruger. Your drive for self-education is genuinely admirable, but you really, [i]really[/i] need to include formal reading in that, because until you do you've not learned Lesson #1: [i]Know How Much You [b]Don't[/b] Know[/i]. You can get a 1st edition of Code Complete (more than adequate) off eBay for a few bucks; ask Santa to send your Xmas present early this year. It's educational, an investment in your future, and better than socks.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I am overestimating my understanding. But It's still not answering my main question of how to make a chunk of code a variable. I do have script to manipulate the other variables like the recipient and such, but using a script to physically alter the code every time I want to use it? That defeats the point of having it as an application, not a script.

Comment: Plus, I get the figurative speech, but I don't believe in "Santa." I knew it was my parents since I was 3! It was actually kinda funny.

Comment: Just thought of something. `sendEmail("Joe", "joel@here.com", "Type your subject here!", "Type your message content here!")` What if I made these variables instead? Set the variables using dialogs and answers, then use the variables in this. Would that work out the same way? (same way the longer script works)

Comment: As examples to explain,  Joe would be "something1" joel@here.com would be "something2" (subject probably won't be manipulated for my use) Content would be "something3"